# Why isn't my property aware of changes made directly to the database

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, ef-code-first

I have a simple View and ViewModel. When you click on the ComboBox of Technicians and select a Technician, the Tests for the SelectedTechnician are displayed in the ListView you see below. This works perfectly well.

**Note** Technician has a one to many relationship with Test and each is an entity (Code-First Entity Framework).

**MainViewModel.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Technicians, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="FullName"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTechnician, Mode=TwoWay}">
        </ComboBox>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTechnician.Tests}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTest}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="271">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Test" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TestTypeName}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private WpfTestBedDb db = new WpfTestBedDb();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Technicians = new ObservableCollection<Technician>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Technician> _technicians;

    public ObservableCollection<Technician> Technicians
    {
        get { return _technicians; }
        set
        {
            _technicians = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Technicians");
        }
    }

    private Technician _selectedTechnician;

    public Technician SelectedTechnician
    {
        get { return _selectedTechnician; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedTechnician != value)
            {
                _selectedTechnician = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTechnician");
            }
        }
    }

    public void LoadTechnicians()
    {
        var query = from tech in db.Technicians
                    select tech;
        foreach (var technician in query)
        {
            Technicians.Add(technician);
        }
    }
}
```

Incidentally, to test out the capabilities of DataBinding on the `ObservableCollection<Technician> Technicians;`, as you see in the ViewModel above, I went into the database through SSMS and added a new Technician WHILE the app was still running. Once my addition had been made, I went to the app and clicked on my ComboBox of Technicians only to find that the list/UI hadn't been updated. And yet, I would have thought that because I had made the property Technicians an ObservableCollection, and one that raises the `OnPropertyChanged("Technicians");`, that the UI would have updated.

I did this experiment to simulate two of the same apps running at the same time, each reading and writing to the same database.

**First Question:** Why isn't the UI updating despite having my ObservableCollection raise OnPropertyChanged? That is, why isn't it aware of the changes made directly to the database (outside the app)?

**Second Question:** What do I need to add so that the collection of Technicians is constantly aware of DB changes? (I thought that is what ObservableCollection was for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short version: most data access code is a **disconnected** model, not a live/connected model.

The "observable" here means "reacts to other changes in that layer", i.e. other .NET code manipulating the object model. Using `ObservableCollection<T>` doesn't make a giant hand reach out over the network from the database to tweak the bits.

Making instantly change-aware systems is more complicated than that; frankly I would suggest looking at something like pub/sub if you genuinely need instant updates. Otherwise, *perhaps* consider polling occasionally.

Additionally, note that if you *do* want to do polling, you can't just re-fetch the object via:

```
var stateNow = db.Technicians.Single(x => x.Id == myId);
```

because that *might just hand you back the same object you already have*; a lot of ORMs have an identity cache built in. To actually re-fetch the object you will need a second db-context instance.

Comment: Given your statement about the code being a disconnected model: Is the 'db' object I have instantiated in my ViewModel just a snapshot of the data at a given moment in time? And that's the reason its not aware of anything "more" without polling for it?

Comment: @IsaiahNelson well, sort of yes and no. It is disconnected, except when it needs to be connected :) EF (and similar) will talk to the DB on your behalf when it needs to, but when it *has* the data, the data is disconnected (meaning: a separate model - whether or not there is an open connection somewhere is unrelated). A data-context by itself contains nothing until it needs to. It doesn't load the entire database.

Comment: Very eye-opening. I guess then the real trick is knowing when to poll and what to poll off of. Simply polling based on a time interval would be too costly. So just to rebuff my understanding: is `ObservableCollection<T>` really then intended for reporting changes with only in-memory objects - objects that are added/deleted from it?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. It may also propagate item-level property changes, I can't remember.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Marc Gravell's answer, and in answer to your second question, you might like to check out the `SqlDependency` class.

Quoting from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx):

> The SqlDependency object represents a query notification dependency between an application and an instance of SQL Server. An application can create a SqlDependency object and register to receive notifications via the OnChangeEventHandler event handler.